# Would a Nvidia Geforce GT 730 video card be compatible with my computer?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

Im trying to get a video card to run highly demanding video games such as DayZ standalone. I dont know a lot about these types of things but my computer has a 150W power supply. im not sure what is required for a Nvidia Geforce 730. My Computer is an Acer Aspire Z1620. It currently has intel HD integrated Graphics which I hear is considered one of the worst video cards available. If Nvidia Geforce GT 730 will not be compatible what is the best video card out there that would be compatible? If you need anymore information i would gladly give it to you from the best of my ability.

Comment: The requirements of the graphic card is listed in the specifications.  The card must both fit in the case but you must also meet the power requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer recommends a minimum of 300W power supply to run this graphics card. So if your PSU has a maximum of 150W it won't be able to run it without trouble.
Also, if I googled it right, your PC is an All-in-one, which in most cases means that you have **no options to upgrade CPU or GPU on that machine**. The problem with those computers is that in order to take up less space, they sacrifice upgrading capabilities.

If you really want to play those games that you can't right now with that computer, you'll have to buy a new one. And if you decide to do so, then make sure that you buy a regular desktop PC, and not an AIO.

Comment: Alright, i will make sure to look over the machine that i get. thank you for the help.